# Thunderbird OpenPGP

Tags: add-on, thunderbird, openpgp

I have started to use openPGP in thunderbird (enigmail 1.4) for signing my messages
But it is generating something like

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA1

signed message by openpgp

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.11 (GNU/Linux)
Comment: Using GnuPG with Mozilla - http://enigmail.mozdev.org/

iQEcasdfasdfasdfasdf.....E
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

If i am not mistaken sha1 is very old how to change for example to sha-3 and how to delete the line comment:....
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can access those properties through Thunderbird Options > Advanced > General > Config Editor… 
(Equivalent to about:config)

Then type `extensions.enigmail.mimeHashAlgorithm`
The following values are available:

- 0 - automatic selection, let GnuPG choose
- 1 - SHA1
- 2 - RIPEMD160
- 3 - SHA256
- 4 - SHA384
- 5 - SHA512
- 6 - SHA224

For the comment, you can go to OpenPGP > Preferences > Display Expert Settings > Advanced > uncheck "Add Enigmail comment in OpenPGP signature".

(Alternatively, from Config editor: `extensions.enigmail.useDefaultComment`.)

Many other settings are detailed here : https://www.enigmail.net/documentation/userprefs.php